# mplfinance candlsticks piling on chart and not moving forward

Tags: python-3.x, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

[image: Candlestick Chart is being updated ever minute but animation not working correctly]

I am fetching the data from csv which is being updated from websocket. in the chart alothough candles are showing but they  squezing the space between candles and getting smaller and smaller.
Please let me know what is wrong I am doing.

```
    fig = mpf.figure(style='binance',figsize=(12,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(ival):
    df = pd.read_csv('bitcoin_data.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    df = df[['minute', 'open', 'high',
             'low', 'close']]
    df.minute = pd.to_datetime(df.minute)
    df = df.set_index('minute')

    ax1.clear()
    mpf.plot(df, ax=ax1, type='candlestick', ylabel='price')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)\

mpf.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that, after some time, you are trying to plot too much data.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Plotting-Too-Much-Data for more information.

The solution would be to modify your animate function to plot only the most recent 500 to 700 candles from your dataframe.

Maybe something like:

```py
if len(df) > 600:
    df = df.iloc[-600:-1,:] 
mpf.plot(df, ax=ax1, type='candlestick', ylabel='price')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It did help in getting the space back when I put 100 candles in the code you provided but previous data before 100 candlesticks does not show.

Comment: It is true that you won't be able to see older data.  The idea is to display a "window" of the most recent activity.  However you should be able to see 500 candles easily (unless you have a very low resolution monitor).  If you attach you csv file (full) I will break it up into smaller csvs and try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  I hope you are doing well. I changed the code a bit and tested it now and it's working. The problem now is it's not showing bitcoin price and space between the chart and the frame is big as shown in screenshot initially.  I am getting the data from websocket and sending it to CSV with the help of pandas and reading it in charts .

Comment: I have formatted the price to 2points float and now it's showing as well.

Comment: You can also adjust the space between the chart and the frame using the [**`scale_padding`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/212#issuecomment-655603896) kwarg.

Comment: I used scale_padding and it worked nicely adjusting the padding in the frame. Daniel thanks alot for your help.   scale_padding={'left': .25, 'top': .5, 'right': 1, 'bottom': 0.75}